# Unable to register host while creating Apache Ambari cluster

Tags: ambari

I am trying to create localhost Apache Ambari cluster on CentOS7. I am using Ambari 2.2.2 binaries downloaded and installed from the Ambari repository with the following commands

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
wget  http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos7/2.x/updates/2.2.2.0/ambari.repo
yum install ambari-server
ambari-server setup
ambari-server start
```

Before starting the server I have done all the necessary preparations steps described on the [Hortonworks](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.1.0.0/bk_Installing_HDP_AMB/content/_prepare_the_environment.html) including the setup of passwordless ssh, which is frequent reason of problems according to the posts found on the internet. I verify it with

```
ssh root@localhost
```

During the creation of cluster in the "Install options" window I enter the name of the host I want to create (localhost in my case) and have already tried both of the options, which are

- providing rsa secret key direktly - in this case the next window
  simply stucks in the "Installing" stage and does not go any further,
  showing no errors
- performing manual registration of hosts.

For the second option I have downloaded and installed ambari-agent

```
yum install ambari-agent
ambari-agent start
```

In case of manual host registration I am getting the following error

**"Host checks were skipped on 1 hosts that failed to register."**.

When I click on "Failed", which in some cases described over the internet is supposed to deliver more precise description of a problem I see the following 
**"Registering with the server...
Registration with the server failed."**

As a result I don't even now where to start searching for the possible reasons of this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ambari cluster nodes need to be configured with a Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN). `localhost` is not an FQDN. You will need to configure the node with an FQDN and then retry the installation. You could use something like: `localhost.local` which is an FQDN. This requirement and how to configure the node to meet it are documented in the pre-requirements. From the [HDP documentation](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.5.0.3/bk_ambari-installation/content/check_dns.html):

> All hosts in your system must be configured for both forward and and reverse DNS.
>
> If you are unable to configure DNS in this way, you should edit the /etc/hosts file on every host in your cluster to contain the IP address and Fully Qualified Domain Name of each of your hosts.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same  *"Registering with the server... Registration with the server failed."* problem just recently.
I found the response on the same topic recommending to take a look at the log file which is located here `/var/log/ambari-agent/ambari-agent.log` from there was able to check that the hostname was set up incorrectly during some other phase of installation (I had it something like ambari.hadoop instead of localhost). So I went to the `/etc/ambari-agent/conf/ambari-agent.ini` and fixed it there.
I know that I'm digging some quite old question, but seems that compiling all that at one place might help someone with the same problem.